# How to Join an empty table

Tags: sql, join, outer-join

I am wondering if it is possible to to create a join that displays null values for an empty table.

The reason I want to do this is I want a user to be able to create a session, which auto increments the ID when created. The user can then add boats through an intermediary Session Boats table using this session ID and selecting a value for boats.

Anyone can then view a join that displays the relevant info for the session comprised of info from multiple tables, such as the SessionID, CoachID, FirstName (of coach), Second Name(of coach), Boat ID, Boat Name.

Once the session is created I would like the user to be able to view this join to see the ID number of the session that will be inserted into Session Boat.

However as session boat is still empty at this point, the Join table does not display and so the ID number cannot be found!

I have already tried using Left Joins and Outer Left Joins and anything else I can think of to Join Session and Session Boat but nothing has worked so far...

Is there a way I can get the Join to display even with an empty table, or any other work around I can use?

Thanks in advance!

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server"     ConnectionString="<%$             ConnectionStrings:Rowing ClubConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT            Session.SessionID,        Session.DateTime, Session.CrewID,  Session.CoachID, Member.FirstName, Member.Surname,     SessionBoats.BoatID, Boat.BoatName, Session.LaunchID
FROM            SessionBoats  LEFT JOIN
                     Session ON Session.SessionID = SessionBoats.SessionID
LEFT JOIN Boat ON SessionBoats.BoatID = Boat.BoatID
LEFT JOIN Coach ON Session.CoachID = Coach.CoachID
LEFT JOIN Member ON Coach.MemberID = Member.ID
"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see everything in `Session Boats` then use left outer joins starting with that table:

```
SELECT s.Session ID, s."Date Time", s."Crew ID", s."Coach ID", m."First Name", m.Surname,
       sb."Boat ID", b."Boat Name", s."Launch ID"
FROM "Session Boats" sb LEFT JOIN
     Session s 
     ON s."Session ID" = sb."Session ID" LEFT JOIN
     Boat b
     ON sb."Boat ID" = b."Boat ID" LEFT JOIN
     Coach c
     ON s."Coach ID" = c."Coach ID" LEFT JOIN
     Member m
     ON c."Member ID" = m.ID;
```

That is the general rule:  start with the table where you want to keep all the rows and then continue with the left join's for all the tables.  I also introduced table aliases to make your query more readable.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but that still doesn't work! I'm displaying the JOIN in a Gridview in ASP.net, does that give any clues maybe? It's still only displaying the JOINS where all fields have values

Comment: Your identifiers all seem to have spaces in them -- this is a very bad idea.  You need to put double quotes or something around all of them.

Comment: Yes sorry I did that when uploading the question, I wasn't sure why I was getting an error from the site when trying to enter a comment! I'll update it now